# NUnit test not reading project file

Tags: c#, reflection, nunit, assemblies

I want to unit test some decompression code. I am putting test files into the project to be used in the tests. I can run the code in a console app and it works fine but when I run the tests they fail.

the test:

```
public void CsvStreamsToCsvStream()
    {
      string dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
      System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

      string file = Path.Combine(dir, @"\TestFiles\Test.csv");
      using (FileStream fstrm = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
      {
        var decompressor = 
          new MemoryDecompresser(fstrm, Path.GetFileName(file));
        var results = decompressor.GetStreams();
        Assert.AreEqual(1, results.Count());
        Assert.AreEqual(results.First().Key, "Test.csv");

      }
    }
```

The console app:

```
namespace TestConsoleApp
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var test = new TestDecompression();
      test.CsvStreamsToCsvStream();
    }
  }
}
```

The project:
[image]

Test Explorer:
[image]

Comment: Ignore this if it's a silly suggestion, but could it be because the test is in a subfolder?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Ben, I think it's more at the fact nUnit is looking the C root for my file instead of the assembly path

Comment: Your *executing assembly* is the test runner. So the location that you retrieve with `GetExecutingAssembly()` is different than in your console app. Try `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(TestDecompression)).Location` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Embed the Resource

[image]

Access the resource vial "GetManifestResourceStream(string)" with Assembly Name. Folder Name. File Name

```
[Test]
    public void CsvStreamsToCsvStream()
    {
      using(Stream fstrm = 
                Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                .GetManifestResourceStream(@"Tests.TestFiles.Test.csv"))
      {
        var decompressor =
          new MemoryDecompresser(fstrm, "Test.csv");
        var results = decompressor.GetStreams();
        Assert.AreEqual(1, results.Count());
        Assert.AreEqual(results.First().Key, "Test.csv");

      }
    }
```